# How to run jupyter notebook on start up on Ubuntu LTS 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, jupyter-notebook, ubuntu-18.04, startup

I simply need to run `jupyter notebook` command on start up without having to do it myself or opening a terminal.
I've tried all 3 solutions in this [link](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/run-command-startup-linux-27796.html), with the shell file having `jupyter notebook` in it, but neither worked.
I think they didn't work because jupyter server requires an opened terminal or something? I am not sure.

Comment: [This post](https://forums.fast.ai/t/run-jupyter-notebook-on-system-boot/749/2) has a few more details that might help you work it out.

Comment: I found solution for it and wrote it below.

Answer (score 1):

So I found an easy way to do it.

There's a default application on Ubuntu called "Start Up Application Preferences". You can find it by writing it on search.
Then click Add, write any name for the application, say Jupyter.
In command, browse and choose jupyter-notebook, which you will find in home/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook.
And finally click on Add.

On next start-up, the server will open automatically.